# How to use formElement.selectionStart & formElement.selectionEnd in TypeScript or Angular Class

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to get seelected text of a textarea. In javascript I can get it by using these two but how to get it in Angular 6.

```
sendMessage(){

     // I want to get SELECTED Text here OF textarea id in Angular 6

    }`
```

-- in JAVASCRIPT I CAN GET IT BY ----

```
 <textarea id="quote" cols="50" rows="5">
Some text here
</textarea>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>

var quotearea = document.getElementById('quote')
var output = document.getElementById('output')
quotearea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    if (this.selectionStart != this.selectionEnd){ // check the user has selected some text inside field
        var selectedtext = this.value.substring(this.selectionStart, this.selectionEnd)
        output.innerHTML = selectedtext
    }
}, false)

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your view, bind your textarea to the `(select)` event and assign a function to that event:

```
 <textarea id="quote" cols="50" rows="5" (select)="select($event)">
     Some text here
 </textarea>
```

In your component:

```
 select(event) {
    const start = event.target.selectionStart;
    const end = event.target.selectionEnd;
    console.log(event.target.value.substr(start, end - start))
 }
```

Each time you select a piece of text in your textarea, the `select()` method described above is called.